# Function clrscr in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

Does today's C or C++ compilers use the `clrscr` system function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`clrscr()` is a nonstandard function (neither mentioned in `ISO C99` nor in `ISO C++-98`) defined in `<conio.h>` (which is not standard compliant itself). However some compilers (like [Turbo C/C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B)) support it as an extension.

Comment: so what we use in linux instead of clrscr

Answer (score 8):

Like all of the stuff in `conio.h`. `clrscr()` has nothing to do with standard C. `conio` is a common API of ancient DOS-based C implementations for lower-level console io - things like clearing the screen, moving the cursor, reading individual keystrokes, etc. I don't know the history but presumably it dates back to before DOS had `ANSI.SYS` to support standard terminal-escape codes for cursor positioning, clearing the screen, changing colors, ...

If you're just playing around learning C, there's no harm in using the `conio` functions, but you should avoid making a habit of `#include <conio.h>`. In most of the questions I've seen on SO where `conio.h` was included, it wasn't even being used... This kind of bad habit leads to senselessly nonportable code.

Comment: `conio.h` is (apart from using the native API functions directly) the only way to get reliable Unicode input and output for the Windows console, so it still plays a role today.

Comment: Isn't it possible to set the console io 'codepage' to UTF-8? I don't it's not possible to set the 'ANSI codepage' to UTF-8 but I thought Windows allowed UTF-8 in other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Also, as an alternative to `conio.h`, you can try using [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/), which provides terminal handling, cursor management, colors and a lot of other functionalities. In particular, it provides the `clear()` function with a similar functionality to the `clrscr()` function you mentioned. For Windows (which must be your case), there is [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) that employs the same API. In particular, `ncurses` complies with the XSI Curses base specification, and it is widely adopted; you should stick to it if any degree of portability matters.

Answer (score 0):

DeathStation 9000 and its ZOG C compiler still use `clrscr()`.

quote from http://dialspace.dial.pipex.com/town/green/gfd34/art/

> It would be unfortunate if any more
>   lives were lost simply because some
>   programmers feel a deep spiritual need
>   to obliterate the display device, and
>   much much more, using ZOG C's Commence
>   Launch (Remote Systems Console
>   Request) function, **clrscr()**.

Answer (score -1):

On Unix-like systems you can use VT100 escape codes.

```
std::cout << "\033[2J" << std::flush;
```

See http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm