# Why Java doesn't support function like clrscr in C?

Tags: java, c, oop, console

I had a question that may sound dumb to many, but I can't stop to post it here as found nothing there on the Internet.

Why does java doesn't have clrscr sort of function that we use in C?

If I created a java concole application that iterates over and over based on user input and then if I want to provide the user an option to clear the screen, then why its not supported in java.

I know there are some ways [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241217/how-to-clear-console-in-java) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console).

Is it something related to Java being OOP (I highly doubt but don't have a concrete answer).

Comment: in real world clrscr is not really wanted. If you need create such app, consider using Swing as GUI - its quite easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOP has nothing to do with it. It's more clrscr is more a function of the environment the Java is running in than Java itself, and so it is not in Java's scope.

Or to put it another way: since Java is cross platform and can be run without a console, the meaning of clrscr has to change depending on how the app is run and on what platform.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it does not exist because of portability issues. Even in C, `clrscr()` [is not really portable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3226340/1734130) - not all platforms support it.

But Java was designed to be write/compile once, run anywhere. And this function does not quite fit into this agenda.